# file is corrupt

Tags: files, elementary-website, filesystem, file-management, pantheon-files

i have a laptop , and i have a eksternal hard disk , and my frien borrow my hardisk to backup something's file .. i dot now what him copied file .. After that, my delete files that have been her backup because he had completed his affair with files that are on my hard disk, hence my delete..after deleted , and how many files deleted in file .Trash -1000 .. and wanted me to delete again , to be cleaner . why can not be removed and writing "can not moving files to trash " .. and all files are erased as it was all . how his solution in order to remove the file without formatting the hard disk ? Sorry if my language is less clear, because I have not yet fluent in English..

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Trash and delete the Trash with the drive plugged in. This automatically deletes the content of the `.Trash` folder(s) from all plugged in devices.